# Bizarre problem with CodeIgniter routing rules

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

I have set two rules :

```
$route['followers/(:num)'] = 'hall/filter/subscribers/$1';
```

And :

```
$route['see/(:num)'] = 'hall/see/$1';
```

But while the first one is working all fine, the second one behaves juste like the 2nd argument (the :num) wasn't passed at all (displaying see/4 gives the hall/see/ page, not hall/see/4 !). This is very odd because from my point of view, those 2 routes work the same way !!

Any idea ?

Edit :

If I change `$route['see/(:num)']` to `$route['foo/see/(:num)']` then it works. This is crazy oO

Answer (score -1):

You should use "" instead '', so it should be

```
$route['followers/(:num)'] = "hall/filter/subscribers/$1";
$route['see/(:num)'] = "hall/see/$1";
```

Comment: Erm, may I ask why I should do that ? Additionally, that has nothing to do with the issue :/ thanks anyway

Comment: Since CodeIgniter was written in PHP, i believe ' is different with ", for example you have declared a variable, `$foo = 'bar';` then that will be different if you do `echo '$foo';` and `echo "$foo";`. And in your issues with CodeIgniter routes, that would be a problem.

Comment: I think I'd write echo $foo with no quote at all. I'll look into that but that did not solve my problem

Comment: Just look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html for clearing this up ok. In that user guide, it use double quotes instead single quoted. If you still not sure, that will be a problem, just check the source code in Route and URI in Codeigniter system folder.

Comment: I don't question your point. I already read ten times the user guide. Fact is : it didn't solve my problem. And in the page you linked, they use double quotes until last example (reserved routes) which is the only working example actually shipped with CI.

Comment: Referencing from your first route rules, i will guess that you put your controller into some sub folder, then what you need is simply `$route['see/(:num)'] = "hall/see/index/$1";`

Comment: my controller is not in a sub folder. The problem cannot come from the controller because the foo/see/(:num) rule works fine !

Comment: Hey, no need to be offensive. I'll here try to help you :) Ok, so its not on subfolder you said, but why you have this route before : `$route['followers/(:num)'] = "hall/filter/subscribers/$1";` ? Its almost likely you have "hall" as sub folder in your controllers directory, and filter controller which have subscribers function. Thats the common uri routes in CI. I just didnt beleve quickly, then CI Route, as you have posted in Bug section in original forums, fails only for you but works for other thousand developer who use it.